# WebDriverIO: browser.debug() to enter REPL, but any command causes it to hang

Tags: debugging, webdriver, read-eval-print-loop

I threw in a `browser.debug()` into my test so that I can view my code real-time in the browser. It successfully pauses the browser, but any command I type into the REPL causes it to hang, and I can't even exit out of the REPL to allow my test to continue running. Anyone know why I can't use the command-line/REPL to control my browser in debug mode?

[image: any command I type in will hang and eventually time out]

Comment: what browser are you testing against?

Comment: @TallyBarak I am testing with chrome

Comment: Are you working with chrome driver directly or with selenium driver? one option is to try and debug the selenium APIs directly via postman to see if it is a selenium / CD issue or Wdio